# Sending a pdf through WhatsApp Business API that is stored in google drive, but I am receiving an error " 12300 - Invalid Content-Type "

Tags: c#, pdf, twilio, whatsapi, media-url

I am trying to send a pdf through WhatsApp Business API that is stored in google drive, but I am receiving an error " 12300 - Invalid Content-Type  " can you help me where am I going wrong also, I want to know how to send a pdf in MediaUrl from my local storage. I tried using Twilio Assets but it's also not working. Here is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var accountSid = " ";
    var authToken = " ";
    TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var mediaUrl = new[] {
        new Uri("google drive link")
    }.ToList();
    
    var messageOptions = new CreateMessageOptions(
        new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+91XXXXXX"));
    messageOptions.From = new PhoneNumber("whatsapp:+XXXXXXXX");
    messageOptions.Body = "Hello how are you?";
    messageOptions.MediaUrl = mediaUrl;
    var message = MessageResource.Create(messageOptions);
    Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Check the content-type of the mediaUrl, Twilio will check the content type header of the url to figure out the MIME type: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/accepted-mime-types

Also, check the size of the PDF. There is a max size (also in doc link above)

Comment: Thanks, for the help can you tell me how to change or set the content-type of mediaurl.